# Multicast from WSL2 to Win does not work

Tags: networking, wsl2, multicast

I'm using [ROS 2](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/) (a robot middleware) both in WSL2 and in the host Windows OS on the same machine.

For communication, ROS 2 uses UDP multicast (it also comes with a handy multicast troubleshooting tool):

> In order to communicate successfully via DDS, the used network
> interface has to be multicast enabled. We’ve seen in past experiences
> that this might not necessarily be enabled by default (on Ubuntu or
> OSX) when using the loopback adapter. See the [original issue](https://github.com/ros2/ros2/issues/552) or [a conversation on ros-answers](https://answers.ros.org/question/300370/ros2-talker-cannot-communicate-with-listener/). You can verify that your current setup
> allows multicast with the ROS 2 tool:
>
> In Terminal 1:
>
> `ros2 multicast receive`
>
> In Terminal 2:
>
> `ros2 multicast send`

So I try the diagnostic:

- send multicast from Win to Win: it works
- send multicast from WSL2 to WSL2: it works
- send multicast from Win to WSL2: it works
- send multicast from WSL2 to Win: DOES NOT WORK

How to enable sending multicast from WSL2 to Windows?

The [ROS 2 documentation](https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/How-To-Guides/Installation-Troubleshooting.html) goes on with:

> If the first command did not return a response similar to:
>
> `Received from xx.xxx.xxx.xx:43751: 'Hello World!'`
>
> then you will need to update your firewall configuration to allow multicast using ufw.
>
> `sudo ufw allow in proto udp to 224.0.0.0/4`
>
> `sudo ufw allow in proto udp from 224.0.0.0/4`

I run the two above `ufw` commands in my WSL2 (ubuntu-22) instance, but still can't send multicast from WSL2 to Win...

Comment: multicast is enabled on the `eth0` interface of the WSL2 guest (`eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 ...`)

Comment: tried to remove all Windows Defender firewall rules, and to grant permissions to all networks again when asked, but didn't solve the issue

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?